# Laravel Api update and delete function

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-5.3

I'm building an API, i'm getting the following error while updating and deleting from table i'm using postman to test my api

```
    //update error
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: update `lessons` set `title` = , `body` = , `completed` = , `updated_at` = 2017-01-03 09:14:10 where `id` = 11)

//delete error
FatalErrorException in LessonsController.php line 80:
Call to a member function delete() on null
```

My controller LessonsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Response;
use App\lesson;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LessonsController extends ApiController {

    protected $lessonTransformer;

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer) {

        $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;

    }

    //fetch all and pass a metadata 'data' 
    public function index() {

        $lessons = Lesson::all();

        return $this->respond([

            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->all())

        ]);
    }


    //fetch by id
    public function show($id) {

        $lesson = Lesson::find($id);

        if(! $lesson) {

            return $this->respondNotFound();

        }

        return $this->respond([

            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transform($lesson)

        ]);
    }


    public function store() {

        if (! input::get('title') or ! input::get('body')) {
            return $this->respondBadRequest();
        }

        Lesson::create(input::all());

        return $this->respondCreated();

    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id) {

        $ulesson = Lesson::find($id);

        $ulesson->title = $request->input('title');
        $ulesson->body = $request->input('body');
        $ulesson->completed = $request->input('completed');
        $ulesson->save();

        return "Sucess updating user #" . $ulesson->id;
    }   


    public function destroy(Request $request) {
        $dlesson = Lesson::find($request->input('id'));

        $dlesson->delete();

        return "Employee record successfully deleted #" . $request->input('id');
    }

}
```

my model Lesson

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lesson extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'completed',];

    //protected $hidden =['title'];
}
```

the store and other functions are working fine

Thank You

Comment: It looks like your `$ulesson->title` is not set in your update function and all those values might be required to execute your update request

Comment: You also might want to look into `$ulesson->fill($request->all());` :)

Comment: i'm sry i'm not getting what exactly i should do

Comment: It seems that within the destroy function
$dlesson = Lesson::find($request->input('id')); does not find anything to delete. You can check if($dlesson) then $dlesson->delete();

Comment: Check out [Laravel form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation). I find this to be one of the cleanest solutions for validaiton. You could have Request validation check that all the required fields are set and this way the controller will never get executed if validation is not passed.

Answer (score 1):

In update
can you dd($request->input('title')) in line 69 
I think you don't sent the value of title

and in delete
I think you have no value in id field

Comment: i'm getting output `null``

Comment: Yes, for this null value it does not find anything to delete, please check which input value you are passing from the form input

Comment: in your postman you add the parameter title body and completed in body form-data ?

Comment: If possible can you show me the screenshot of the postman screen or the form you are submitting

Comment: you should do dd($request->all())

Comment: dd($request) it will show class of request not error

Comment: @Mr Robot please check your lessons table to find the id 11 exist or not

Comment: my bad forgot to import db

Comment: you have not any Model in App directory named lesson that you have used by using namespace in your controller

Answer (score 1):

[image: The image of postman]

Please check you postman and set it like this

Comment: sir that's a POST request it's working fine the data is inserting to database but how to perform update

Comment: Ok you just change method in postman from POST to PUT or PATCH

Answer (score 1):

i just downloaded Insomnia and tested every thing is working fine as expected

i don't know why it's not working in postman though

Answer (score -1):

**Laravel APi Update Function...**

> **According to this query no need to define keys**

### Controller Function

`

```
public function update(Request $request){

       $reqdata = $request->all(); 

        $reqdata['date_created'] = date('Y-m-d');

         $lesson= Lesson::where('id',$request->id)->update($reqdata);

        if ($lesson) {

            return 'true';

        }else{

            return 'false';

        }

    }  `
```

[Your data type as attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVcPF.png)